# React JS: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have a react app that uses stripe npm packages and is currently giving me the following error.

> Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://m.stripe.network 'sha256-e/Jqu4k9Gk1ZCWO6StAsfhF3i7qgIwfuitaD1g9DyvE='".

When I add the following meta tag, it stops giving this particular error but it blocks all the rest of the JS files including the local bundle files and the app doesn't load.

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="script-src 'unsafe-inline' https://m.stripe.network;"
/>
```

How can I fix the meta tag so that it only applies to https://m.stripe.network

Appreciate any help on this.

**Update:** I'm no longer seeing this issue. Looks like Stripe might have fixed it.

Comment: I'd really suspect that what is happening is Stripe's code is enforcing a (very good) security policy, and that is causing an error to be flagged in *your code*.  Evaluating strings as Javascript is a security hole a few kilometers wide, and should never be used.

Comment: @LeadDreamer I'm not sure why Stripe has JS code that evaluates strings as Javascript. Anyway, I am no longer getting the issue now. Looks like Stripe might have fixed it.

Comment: I'm getting the same error, how did you solve that?