# Laravel and Stripe: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script

Tags: javascript, laravel, stripe-payments

I use `Stripe` in my `Laravel` application which is `Vue` in the front, I add `<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>` at the header section everything was fine. recently I receive the following security warning in my `console.log`.

```
Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src https://m.stripe.network 'sha256-e/Jqu4k9Gk1ZCWO6StAsfhF3i7qgIwfuitaD1g9DyvE='".
```

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72684642/react-js-refused-to-evaluate-a-string-as-javascript) question describe the same problem in `Reactjs` but there is no solution.

Update:
Adding the meta tag like this,  `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://m.stripe.network 'sha256-e/Jqu4k9Gk1ZCWO6StAsfhF3i7qgIwfuitaD1g9DyvE='"/>`
does not let other script  run, and cause this console error

`Refused to load the script '<URL>' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' <URL> 'sha256-e/Jqu4k9Gk1ZCWO6StAsfhF3i7qgIwfuitaD1g9DyvE='". Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.`

Answer (score 0):

you can add this CSP(content security policy) directive `"script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' https://m.stripe.network 'sha256-e/Jqu4k9Gk1ZCWO6StAsfhF3i7qgIwfuitaD1g9DyvE='`

Comment: Adding that script as meta tag does not solve the problem and cause more console errow, I updated the question with your answer.

Comment: do you have a hosted page where I could see the error myself?

Comment: yes, look at https://tingsapp.com